# How to use dojo dictionary object and dojo.mixin() function?

Tags: dojo

I have a function like this that I need to override it.

myfunction.getExtraConfig=function() { return {}; };

I need to pass in an object and have it return multiple values.

How do I use a dictionary to do this {prop1: 1, prop2: 3}?

How do I use dojo.mixin() to add the return value?

Is there any sample code I can refer to?

Answer (score 1):

Dojo's mixin function only mixes objects' properties. The return value in your `getExtraConfig` function is not an object property.

I'm not sure this is what you want, but one way to alter the return value from `getExtraConfig` is to use dojo/aspect:

```
define(["dojo/_base/lang", "dojo/aspect"], function(lang, aspect){
  //...
  aspect.after(myfunction, "getExtraConfig", function(original){
      return lang.mixin(original, {prop1: 1, prop2: 3});
  });
  //...
});
```